# save avro file to Hbase Apache NIFI

Tags: hbase, avro, apache-nifi

I'm getting data from ORACLE DB, and i want to save it in hbase without using (convertAvroToJson and putHbaseJSON)

From oracle i'm getting 4 attribute like this : 
a: Text
b: Text
c: Text
d: Binary

is there any way too save these attributes directly from the avro file

Note: The only reason that prevents me using JSON is the BINARY attribute that could contains (" or ')

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do this with out-of-the-box processors provided by Apache NiFi. You would need to implement a new processor like PutHBaseAvro that could go directly from Avro to the HBase mutations, and properly handle the binary data.

There is an AbstractPutHBase class that can be extended to more easily implement a new put HBase processor:

https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/e4b7e47836edf47042973e604005058c28eed23b/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-hbase-bundle/nifi-hbase-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/hbase/AbstractPutHBase.java

You would just have to implement the following method:

```
protected abstract PutFlowFile createPut(final ProcessSession session, final ProcessContext context, final FlowFile flowFile);
```

Which would read the content of the FlowFile as Avro and convert to the PutFlowFile.

If you are interested in working on this and contributing it back, it would be a nice edition to the HBase processors.